# Mathematical structure of time-dependent Hamiltonians

Tags: abstract-algebra, hilbert-spaces, quantum-mechanics, automorphism-group

In quantum mechanics the states of a physical system live on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ and the Hamiltonian operator can be seen as a map $H_0: \mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{H}$. Algebraically this corresponds to an automorphism in the space of states which I will abstractly call $C$ forgetting the necessary for now restriction of the Hilbert space. Thus we view Hamiltonian operators $H_0$ as group elements:
$$
H_0 \in Aut(C)
$$

More generally, one can consider time varying Hamiltonians $H(t)$. These take the generic form:
$$
H(t) = H_0 + \sum_{i\geq 1} c_i H_i(t)
$$
where $c_i$ are coefficients valued in a field like $\mathbb{C}$ or such and $H_i$ are functions that contain the "time" information. As a matter of fact, in quantum computing, one considers the time varying part to be a result of some external fields $\epsilon(t)$:
$$
H_i(t) = h_i + \sum_{j} \epsilon_{ij}(t)\tilde{h}_{ij}.
$$

**Question**
Does the space of time-varying Hamiltonians have a different algebraic structure than that of $Aut(C)$? Or, even better, what could be a good description of the functions $\epsilon(t)$?

The time dependence is a bit confusing for me but that said, I can totally see that for a fixed time $t=t'$, $$H(t)|_{t=t'} \in Aut(C).$$

So what is the best description for $H(t)$ generically as well as for the external fields $\epsilon(t)$?

Comment: Don't you just get a function $\mathbb{R}\to Aut(C)$, mapping $t\mapsto H(t)$?

Comment: Sure, I just wonder if there is a "global" way to view it, incorporating the action of $H(t)$ for all $t$. Not sure if it makes sense?